How to encourage root growth on budding grape vine hardwood cuttings
I have a few grape vine cuttings which started to grow leaves before growing roots.
What can I do to help them grow roots and survive? What is the most important?
Will the growing leaves consume the resources needed for roots?
I'm keeping them in slightly moist soil on a slightly warm heater, see the pictures.




I would not worry too much. Grape vine will create roots in most conditions. Just if they are old world grapes (so Vitis vinifera) and you do not want to graft it, you should keep soil sandy (to avoid parasites).
